# Vis network nodes not scaling with internal labels

Tags: vis.js

I am trying to build a network with vis with labels inside the nodes where the text scales with the value. Based on the 'scaling' [documentation for nodes](http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html), this should be possible.

I took the example network code from the [getting started section of the documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/network/) and added values to the nodes. If I set the shape to something with the label external (like 'square'), the nodes change size: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avbsb8fr/)

But if I change to shape where the label is inside the node, they no longer scale: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avbsb8fr/1/)

I'm guessing it's a problem with my options, but I did the part of setting nodes.scaling.label.enabled to true:

```
var options = {
    nodes: {
        shape: 'square',
        scaling: {
            label: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: 5 year later I have the same issue, I ended up setting the node.font.size instead of the node.value and that works for any shape with the label inside.